# Python sharepoint connection - unable to access

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

I am trying to access my sharepoint site using python. The sharepoint URL looks something like this: https://companyname.sharepoint.com/teams/mysitename. Following tutorials online on creating sites in sharepoint, somehow my site URL becomes https://companyname.sharepoint.com/teams/mysitename instead of https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitename and this causes an issue trying to create the sharepoint-python connection.

I am referring to this document https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html. The methods used in the document do not work when the domain name uses 'teams' instead of 'sites'. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!